# Extracting year from dataset in python - year appears a decimal point

Tags: python, pandas, date, jupyter-notebook, year2038

Trying to extract year from dataset in python

```py
df["YYYY"] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df["Date"]).year
```

`year` appears as decimal point in the new column.

```
YYYY
2001.0
2002.0
2015.0
2022.0
```

How to just have year appear with no decimal points?

Comment: can you share your df samples

Comment: what is the output of `df.loc[df['YYYY'].isna(), 'Date']`?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have null values in you input resulting in NaNs and a float type for your column.

No missing values:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01']).year

Int64Index([2022], dtype='int64')
```

Missing values:

```
pd.DatetimeIndex(['2022-01-01', '']).year

Float64Index([2022.0, nan], dtype='float64')
```

I suggest to use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) combined with [`convert_dtypes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.convert_dtypes.html):

```
pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2022-01-01', ''])).dt.year.convert_dtypes()

0    2022
1    <NA>
dtype: Int64
```

Or to extract directly the year from the initial strings. But for that we would need a sample of the input.

Answer (score 0):

sample program for your problem

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['3/10/2000', '3/11/2000', '3/12/2000']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date']).year
print(df['year'])
```

pandas takes care of date by itself

if not we can directly specify as

```
df["date_feild"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date_feild"])
```

hope it will make things clear to you.

if not can you specify the df samples